# Proof for an ACT math question?

Tags: polynomials, proof-explanation

A polynomial in x has m nonzero terms. Another polynomial in x has n nonzero terms, where m is less than n. These polynomials are multiplied and all like terms are combined. The resulting polynomial has a maximum of how many nonzero terms? How would you prove that the answer is mn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
& (A+B+C+D)(X+Y+Z) \\[12pt]
= {} & \phantom{{}+{}} A(X+Y+Z) \\
& {} + B(X+Y+Z) \\
& {} + C(X+Y+Z) \\
& {} + D(X+Y+Z) \\[12pt]
= {} & \phantom{{}+{}} AX+AY+AZ \\
& {} + BX+BY+BZ \\
& {} + CX+CY+CZ \\
& {} + DX+DY+DZ \\[12pt]
= {} & \text{a sum of }4\times3\text{ terms}.  
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Each non-zero coefficient in the product must be the result of at least one pair from the original polynomials so the number cannot exceed $mn$.

$mn$ is a possible result, for example from $(x^{(m-1)n}+x^{(m-2)n}+\cdots+x^{2n}+x^{n}+1)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\cdots+x^2+x^1+1)$